# Python extrapolation errror

Tags: python, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate on 2D-data but keep getting the error `could not convert string to float: 'extrapolate'`. I am pretty sure that the value for which I get the error is not outside the interval I used for the interpolation.

I just post my specific example because in order to help me with the error you don't need to understand the certain function I used.

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as si
import math as m

def C_prime_function(M,v):
    return si.norm.cdf(M/v + v/2) - m.exp(-M)*si.norm.cdf(M/v - v/2)
    
C_prime_function_vectorized = np.vectorize(C_prime_function)

x_coarse = np.arange(0.000001,5.5,0.5)
y_coarse = np.arange(-0.5,0.6,0.1)
v_coarse, M_coarse = np.meshgrid(x_coarse,y_coarse)
C_prime_true = C_prime_function_vectorized(M_coarse,v_coarse)

f = interp2d(v_coarse,M_coarse,C_prime_true,kind='linear',fill_value='extrapolate')

print(f(0.000001,0.5))
```

So I thought for `fill_value = 'extrapolate'` Python would automatically extrapolate data that is near/outside the interval. But even for `fill_value = 'nan'` (which I read should lead to an automatic extrapolation), this doesn't work.

Greetings

Felix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead

```
f = interp2d(v_coarse,M_coarse,C_prime_true,kind='linear',bounds_error = False)
```

your code then prints

```
[0.39339549]
```

`fill_value` should either be omitted or a number, not a string, per [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html)

And one more thing -- if you want to explicitly pass the default value to `fill-value` it is not `fill_value = 'nan'` but  `fill_value = None`, which is the way to pass null values in Python (whereas `'nan'` is just a string). You still need `bounds_error = False` though

Comment: I would advise `fill_value = np.nan` rather than `None` so that further calculations can be performed without throwing errors.